# Can we have multi line option for kendo ui masked textbox

Tags: kendo-ui, maskedtextbox

Can anyone help me with kendo ui masked textbox.

How can I give a multi line option to a kendo ui masked textbox.

Answer (score 1):

How about this using a text area ?

```
<textarea data-role="maskedtextbox"
          data-mask="(999) 000-0000-00000-aaa (234580)"
          rows="4"
          data-bind="visible: isVisible,
          enabled: isEnabled,
          value: phoneNumber,
          events: { change: onChange }"
          style="width: 200px"></textarea>
```

Please take a look at [this kendo dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/oRexE)